# how to pass an array to AppDelegate.m?

Tags: class, cocos2d-iphone

I have a simple question.
I need to pass an Array that I used in the mainGameScene to appDelegate and the following is a simplified version of my code.

in mainGameScene.h

```
@interface mainGameScene : CCLayer
{
    CCArray *gameObjectArray;
}
```

and in mainGameScene.m I have a method to get the array:

```
-(CCArray)getArray:
{
    return gameObjectArray;
}
```

in AppDelegate.h, I create an instance of mainGameScene:

```
@interface AppController : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, CCDirectorDelegate>
{
     mainGameScene *mainGameScene;
}
```

in AppDelegate.m, I try to access the Array by:

```
-(void) applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication*)application
{   
    CCArray *gameObjectArray = [mainGameScene getArray];
    CCLOG(@"numOfObjects = %d", getArray.count);
}
```

for some reasons the numOfObjects it printed out always 0;

Can anyone give me a quick answer on why this happens? and how should I implement it? Thank you in advanced for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the AppDelegate look like:

```
-(void) applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication*)application
{   
    CCArray *gameObjectArray = [mainGameLayer getArray];
    CCLOG(@"numOfObjects = %d", gameObjectArray.count);
}
```

I don't see where those other variables are coming from.

Comment: oh, I made a mistake I'll clear it, sorry. any idea what's going wrong?

Comment: You have `inGameLayer` mentioned in your code, as well as `getArray` as a variable, not a method.

Comment: OK, I just corrected, is it make more sense now? Can you tell me why the gameObjectArray.count always 0?

Comment: getArray is a method in mainGameLayer which simply returns gameObjectArray that's in mainGameLayer.

Comment: Sorry, I'm totally confused by your code.  You mention mainGameScene but in your AppDelegate.h you say mainGameLayer.

Comment: oh my god, I'm so sorry, I am so not used to putting code not in Xcode.